# Haskell: Instantiating Show for a Algebraic Type

Tags: haskell, types

I have the data type:

```
data Posn a = Posn Int Int a
```

I want to make a custom Show instance for it that displays the two Ints as an ordered pair, like this:

```
showPosn :: Show a => Posn a -> String
showPosn (Posn l c x) = show (l,c) ++ (' ' : show x)
```

I tried this:

```
instance Show (Show a => Posn a) where
  show = showPosn
```

but this gives me the error "Illegal instance declaration".

What's frustrating is that `deriving Show` works just fine. So, my question to you: What do I need to do to get my Show instance?

Comment: It's totally natural to make this kind of mistake while learning; that said, from it I can tell that you are fairly new to the language.  Making a language is a great way to learn Haskell, I just recommend keeping an open mind rather than trying to fix it before you know anything about it.

Comment: @luqui Thank you for the calm, tolerant answer. I made this question after a late night night of coding, so I guess my frustration was showing. And yeah-- I am kind of new to Haskell. I'm a Lisp kiddy and I just recently got into type theory.

Comment: Also, if you think Haskell's type system is more or less 'crippled DTP', you might want to try Agda or Idris after getting familiar with Haskell.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's okay, you just have the syntax a little wrong:

```
instance (Show a) => Show (Posn a) where
    show = showPosn
```

By the way, this isn't GADTs, but regular algebraic data types.